# Insert string at location Objective-C

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsstring

I'm making an app the has 'hotkeys' in it and when you tap the hotkey it should insert a character at the location you are typing at.
I'm using a `UITextView` with editing on.

[image]

What I want do do is insert the text right *after* the blue cursor.
Is this possible?

Comment: What classes are you using to hold/edit the text?

Comment: See edit... `UITextView` with edit enabled

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to use the `insertText:` method of `UITextView`, which is declared in its implementation of the `UIKeyInput` protocol (which is a super-protocol of `UITextInput`, which `UITextView` implements.)

Comment: A little bit on *how* to do this?

Comment: You just call `insertText:` with the character you want to insert on your `UITextView` instance; I don't think there's much more to say than that.

Comment: One line? So much better and easier.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the location of the cursor by using

```
int position = txtView.selectedRange.location;
```

Then you will need to get the string from the text view and insert your own string

```
NSMutableString *str = [txtView.text mutableCopy];
[str insertString:@"YourString" atIndex:position];
txtView.text = str;
```

This may scroll the text view and lose your current cursor, if you dont want to lose it, you will need to subclass UITextView and do some work inside the drawRect

Comment: Subclass? If I'm asking too much you could just point me to a documentation link.

Comment: here is a demo on how to do it http://miphol.com/muse/2009/05/subclassing-uitextview.html

Comment: Just in case sb. doesn't want the cursor to end up at the end, i added  2 lines of code, to set it back to the old position:
    NSRange noteRange = [noteView selectedRange];
 /* other code */   [noteView setSelectedRange: noteRange];